# Better Python 3 REPL libreadline history

Tags: linux, windows, python-3.x, read-eval-print-loop

I don't know exactly how to title this, hence the likely awkward title.

Let's say I wrote some code like this in the python3.6 REPL:

```
>>> with open('a.txt') as input, open('b.txt', 'w') as out:
...   for i, line in enumerate(input):
...     if i % 4 == 0:
...       out.write(line)
... 
>>>
```

After typing this, I realize that I actually meant to output a line when `i % 4 == 1`. No worries, I press the `UP ARROW` key four times to arrive at the first line `with ... out:`, and I press `ENTER` to type it in. At this point, the repl looks like this (with my cursor on the last line):

```
>>> with open('a.txt') as input, open('b.txt', 'w') as out:
...   for i, line in enumerate(input):
...     if i % 4 == 0:
...       out.write(line)
... 
>>> with open('a.txt') as input, open('b.txt', 'w') as out:
...
```

I distinctly remember the functionality where I could now do a single `DOWN ARROW` keypress to query the second line, `for i, ... (input):`, since the previous line was also queried from the history. I would then continue to do series of a single `DOWN ARROW` followed by `ENTER` until I reached the line I wanted to modify. This is much quicker then doing `n` keypresses for every single line.

I can't remember if this was on macOS or on Windows or what, but I'm on `Ubuntu 17.04` with the `python3.6` repl and I can't figure out how to enable that functionality.

Does anyone know what I'm referring to, and how I can enable it? Thank you for any advice.

Comment: That's how the Windows console input history works when the "Discard Old Duplicates" option isn't enabled. If you press F7 you'll see a popup that highlights the line you're on in the history buffer. It's not a readline library loaded in the current process; it's all implemented by the console itself (conhost.exe) when doing a processed read via `ReadConsole` / `ReadFile`. The console has a set of history buffers, one for each executable (by image name) that's attached to it -- up to the number of history buffers configured in the options.

Comment: Man I was really hoping that this wouldn't be terminal specific... Is there anything like this on linux for the Python REPL that you know of?

Comment: On Linux you're using GNU readline, which is an in-process library. It's configurable, but I don't know how to make it work like the Windows console in this regard.